# A Friendly Challenge Cipher

Tags: cipher

I have bought a game card for a friend for his birthday. One of those cards that comes with a code that you enter for in-game currency, but I can't just let him have it without messing with him a little. I've created a somewhat simple cipher I believe and wanted to get some feed back if my riddles for figuring out the cipher are easy enough for an average person to solve without TOO much trouble.
 Riddles are as follows:

I am the authority of these lands
'Tis my job to protect them, and enforce their rules
To all who may choose to enter my domain
Obey these rules you must.

If I think you may not be following these rules
A set of tests I will give you
Sing these simple 1, 2, 3s
And maybe you will pass.

But to sing them simply as they are
Would be an easy task
So to test you truly we must alter them
Sing them end to start to pass my first test.

If you found my first test easy
Then hopefully my next will be too
Now that you know my song in altered form
Let's mix it up again!

Last time 'twas but back to begin
This time though will be a bit more tricky
Sing my song till you are past the point of no return
Then start the count from there to 1 again.

Now if you've passed my tests and tricks
My code should be quite a simple one
To claim your reward, simply apply your skills below
And onward you may go.

Secret Message:
Fyq fmvj qmu tfeu xsnnbi yz m ukmbi hvya yzi ty tiz?

Comment: P.S. the secret message posted here is not the game code.  :)

Comment: I don't think this is easy enough for an average person to solve. I'm an average person, and I can't really solve this, so I'm thinking this might take at least half an hour to solve. Maybe try a simpler riddle for your friend.

Comment: @The Bunz, the average person who knows about ciphers, or just average anybody? Is figuring out what you're referring to by "1, 2, 3s" part of the puzzle?

Comment: Btw, welcome to Puzzling.SE! Check out https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour for another badge.

Comment: Well, if The Bunz's friend knows about ciphers, then they could solve the puzzle quicker. But if someone who doesn't know how to solve a cipher (like me, a complete loser who can only make puzzles, not solve them) tries to solve it, it'd take a while for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted here what I was going for with each part of the riddle, so if you can think of perhaps a better way to hint at or suggest these answers I'm open to suggestions.

I am the authority of these lands
'Tis my job to protect them, and enforce their rules
To all who may choose to enter my domain
Obey these rules you must.

> I'm referring to a police officer, specifically traffic cop. The rules you must obey are traffic laws.

If I think you may not be following these rules
A set of tests I will give you
Sing these simple 1, 2, 3s
And maybe you will pass.

But to sing them simply as they are
Would be an easy task
So to test you truly we must alter them
Sing them end to start to pass my first test.

> This is referring to being asked to sing the ABCs in reverse to prove your sober.

If you found my first test easy
Then hopefully my next will be too
Now that you know my song in altered form
Let's mix it up again!

Last time 'twas but back to begin
This time though will be a bit more tricky
Sing my song till you are past the point of no return
Then start the count from there to 1 again.

> Past the point of no return refers to being past halfway, so in the ABCs backwards that would be the letter 'M'
> (z  y  x  w  v  u  t  s  r  q  p  o  n  m  l  k  j  i  h  g  f  e  d  c  b  a).
> Then give each letter a number so the cipher comes out to the following:
> A = 13 B = 12 C = 11 D = 10 E = 9 F = 8 G = 7 H = 6 I = 5 J = 4 K = 3 L = 2 M = 1 N = 26 O = 25 P = 24 Q = 23 R = 22 S = 21 T = 20 U = 19 V = 18 W = 17 X = 16 Y = 15 Z = 14
> The final part which is not mentioned in the riddle is that each letter has been swapped with the letter that falls in that new position in the normal version of the alphabet, so since M = 1 then M = A so on so forth. Giving us the following:
> A = M | B = L | C = K | D = J | E = I | F = H | G = G | H = F | I = E | J = D | K = C | L = B | M = A | N = Z | O = Y | P = X | Q = W | R = V | S = U | T = T | U = S | V = R | W = Q | X = P | Y = O | Z = N

Comment: Well, I was way off base. Still... with 1 being Rot13 and 10 being Voynich, I'd rate this puzzle's difficulty at a 2. Minus the riddle, it's a rot13(fgenvtugsbejneq zbabnycunorgvp fhofgvghgvba pvcure). If your friend is into ciphers, and you give them more than a sentence or two, they'll be able to ignore the riddle and crack the cipher easily. If they are not into ciphers, you may have to give them some hints before they are able to derive the key from that riddle.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I know nothing of ciphers and I doubt they do either so I think I am going to have to make my hints a little more obvious.